# Updating Parsed Json data into Listview

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I've been trying to store the parsed Json data into Listview but it's not working.

I retreived some data(which is in the form of table) from a server and then i parsed it into Json object.
The whole code worked well. It displays the retreived data when i use 'Toast' in my android activity.
      Please help me to store this parsed data in Listview.

### Here is my code

```
public void clickbutton(View v) {
        try {

            // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            //
            HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
            // p.setParameter("name", pvo.getName());
            p.setParameter("user", "1");

            // Instantiate an HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);
            String url = "http://bhavit.xtreemhost.com/webservice1.php?user=1&format=json";
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Instantiate a GET HTTP method
            try {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
                //
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        7);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("details", "1"));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                        responseHandler);
                // Parse
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String s = e.getString("post");
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);

                    map.put("time", jObject.getString("time"));
                    map.put("latitude", jObject.getString("latitude"));
                    map.put("longitude", jObject.getString("longitude"));

                    mylist.add(map);

                }
                Toast.makeText(this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                **String[] columns = new String[] { "Time", "Latitude", "Longitude" };
                int[] renderTo = new int[] { R.id.time, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude };

                ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.geo_ponts_list, columns, renderTo);
                setListAdapter(listAdapter);**

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - end");


        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void setListAdapter(ListAdapter listAdapter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public class Data {
        // private List<User> users;
        public List<details> users;

        // +getters/setters
    }

    static class details {
        String latitude;
        String longitude;
        String time;

        public String Longitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public String Latitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public String Time() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setUserName(String value) {
            longitude = value;
        }

        public void setidusers(String value) {
            latitude = value;
        }
```

---

There is no error but the activity doesn't show the values in the Listview but values can be seen using Toast.!
[Output Of Activity using Toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQlWR.jpg)

### **here is my geo_ponts_list.xml file**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/time"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/latitude"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/longitude"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

---

Comment: I'm also using a Button 'Retreive data', when i click it, then the activity Toasts the Retreived data.  Do i need to attach Listview with that Button.

Comment: Can you post your layout file geo_ponts_list.xml as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to mention:

Check Again that Your HashMap gets the correct values or not,

Log your values in your for loop like `Log.i("item",jObject.getString("time"));`

and second thing make your own `custom list Adapter` class,

**[USING THIS EXAMPLE SAME AS YOURS](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)**

Answer (score 2):

It seems the SimpleAdapter you're using should be case sensitive? You're passing "Time", "Latitude", and "Longitude" as your columns but your JSON object contains "time", "latitude", and "longitude".

Comment: Have you looked through your JSON? Is responseBody being correctly parsed?

Answer (score 2):

I gave your code a go, and as Quenton said, it's the problem with case that makes the listview not show anything.

```
**String[] columns = new String[] { "Time", "Latitude", "Longitude" };
            int[] renderTo = new int[] { R.id.time, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude };

            ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.geo_ponts_list, columns, renderTo);
            setListAdapter(listAdapter);**
```

You should modify columns variable to have the values in small caps. It worked for me.

```
String[] columns =  new String[] {"time", "latitude', 'longitude'};
```